# How do I prevent a texture from stretching when using a boolean modifier on the object?

Tags: materials, shaders

I made a lava planet and used the boolean modifier on a cube to "eat" it away.
For the planet I made a material in the Shader Workspace. When I move the cube on the planet and it eats the planet away the material is moving and stretching.

How can I "lock" the material on the planet?

[image: Planet without cube on it]

So here you can see, that the material is stretching and not staying in the position it is in the first picture:

[image: Planet with cube on it]

So how can I "lock" the material on the "skin" of the planet, so it doesn't move or anything, when the cube is "eating" the planet?

[image]

Comment: Maybe use 'object' from the texture coordinates? Could generate other issues, though

Comment: strange, it should not stretch, could you show your nodes organization?

Comment: i have added nodes Organisation (the texture coordinate node was just added by me and it works, but what other issues can it generate?)

Comment: OK so 'object' does the job? Other issues could be on particular texture nodes that does not handle XYZ such has brick texture. But 'object' or 'generated' cause the same issue about that.

Comment: maybe share your file if it doesn't bother you, I don't see what's the problem

Comment: @moonboots The problem is or was about the coordinates 'generated' = 'between 0 and 1' whatever the object size is. 'object' = 'coordinates in object space' (so that's independant of the object size.

Comment: @lemon, I can't reproduce his problem, either with generated or object, and the boolean should not affect the object size...

Comment: @moonboots, have added an answer to explain it better.

Answer (score 3):

If using generated texture coordinates, such as:

[image]

The coordinates will be between 0 and 1, whatever the object size is.

So if we apply a boolean, the resulting object size changes and the texture stretches (which can be an interesting effect, by the way):

[image]

If we use 'object', like here:

[image]

Coordinates are stable in object space as they are the real coordinates, not remapped between 0 and 1.

So:

[image]

Comment: Ok, it looks like it happens in 2.8 but not in 2.79   ;)   I was testing in 2.79

Comment: Yes you really solved my Problem . Thank you a lot !!!

Comment: @moonboots, effectively... and curiously! It seems the depsgraph is handled very differently (distant past 2.79 it seems ; ) Or is it an option somewhere?

Comment: you mean the fact that the modifier is somehow applied before the material?

Comment: @moonboots, yes. Intended or regression? What do you think? To me that was logical but did not remember that was not the case in 2.79

Comment: I don't know yet what's the best, I guess they must have thought about it and it's for the best?

Comment: @moonboots FYI was about to report a maybe bug. But before that I've tested a lattice in 2.79 and the texture stretches. So my opinion is 2.80 is more coherent.

Comment: Edit: yes you're actually right it's more coherent